# Separate columns in csv Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with the following columns:

```
"Advertising, Marketing, Promotions, Public Relations, and Sales Managers"
```

I am trying to separate those strings with delimiter in python. Following is my code so far:

```
with open('output-onlinecsvtools.csv', 'r') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

However, this only does the job for the first comma and also creates a duplicate. I am not concerned about the duplicates as I can remove them but I thought delimiter works for as many commas as they are in the cell.

Comment: Have you tried to read the file in `Pandas`? It's as simple as `pandas.read_csv("output-onlinecsvtools.csv", ",")`.

Comment: @XiaoyuLu Nice and easy solution. Did not know about pandas at all. Thank you !

Comment: @XiaoyuLu, you don't need to define `columns` separately just define it while reading the file, i have Just placed the answer based on the understanding you asked, hope that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Pandas solution, you can try:

This will read, delemit based on comm, However it will be good to define the desired columns while creating the DataFrame(df) So, when you will do other operation later on these columns it will not read the whole CSV file rather will look the data on these columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csvFile', ',', usecols=['Advertising', 'Marketing', 'Promotions', 'Public Relations', 'Sales Managers'])
```

OR, You can specify a new argument `sep`

```
df = pd.read_csv('csvFile', sep=',' , usecols=['Advertising', 'Marketing', 'Promotions', 'Public Relations', 'Sales Managers'])
```

Comment: The problem is my file has around 1000 columns and just one row.

Comment: @Mario, Okay that's fine but you told you need to choose only few columns as you asked in the the Post. do you need anything to be of these columns? However in the answer i've shown how to select particular column you needed.